# Simulate Arival Times in a Poisson Process

Tags: excel, simulation, poisson

In Excel, I want to generate arrival times for a simulation (illustration) of a [M/M/1 queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/1_queue).

Jobs arrive according to a Poisson process. I found `POISSON` and [`POISSON.DIST`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/poisson-dist-function-HP010335695.aspx) functions in Excel, but not an inverse Poisson distribution function. I figured that since Normal distribution with mean `λ` and variance `λ` is supposed to be a good approximation of Poisson distribution (given large enough time intervals), I tried to use inverse Normal distribution function to simulate the intervals between arrivals:

```
=NORM.INV(RAND(), mean, SQRT(mean))
```

And to compute the arrival times (Excel format of time is in fractions of a day):

```
=IFERROR(previous_time + interval_in_seconds/60/60/24, 0)
```

I am no expert in statistics, but **my simulated intervals look a bit too regular for it to be a Poisson process** (see illustration below for `λ = 1/10s`) - what am I doing wrong plz??

[image: normal.inv]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized my mistake after a good night's sleep that there is an important distinction between these 2 concepts:

### [Poisson Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process)

> A renewal process with exponentially distributed renewal intervals.

### [Poisson Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)

> A discrete probability distribution that expresses the probability of a given number of events occurring in a fixed interval of time.

So while number of jobs that arrive according to Poisson process during a time interval `x` follow Poisson distribution with parameter `λx`, the inter-arrival times of this process are distributed **exponentially**.

Inverse exponential function [can be written in Excel](http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?t=163575) as follows:

```
 =-LN(RAND()) * mean
```

Illustration for `λ = 1/10s`:

[image: exp.inv]